# Magento2 price filter with special price for configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, special-price

For Configurable product how can we get price filter with special price in magento2? Now its filtering with original price.
if i have a product with retail price:20 and special price:10, price filter is working with retail price. How to change it to special price range.